# Lens access Map Key

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have some problems using Lens library to acces Map Data type.

```
data Card
  = Ferme
  | Boulangerie

data PlayerState = PlayerState {
  _psCards      :: Map Card Int,
  } deriving (Show)


data GameState = GameState {
  _gsPlayers      :: [PlayerState]
                 } deriving (Show)
```

I have difficulties accessing the `Map`

```
step :: (MonadState s m, HasGameState s, MonadIO m) => m ()
step = do
    i <- use $ gsPlayers . ix 0 . psCards . ix Ferme
```

with the following error:

```
    • Could not deduce (Monoid Int) arising from a use of ‘ix’
      from the context: (MonadState s m, HasGameState s, MonadIO m)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   step :: forall s (m :: * -> *).
                           (MonadState s m, HasGameState s, MonadIO m) =>
                           m ()
```

Is this because I use `ix` with different argument in the same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `ix` is a Traversal, but `use` expects a Lens. The difference is that a Lens always has exactly one target. A Traversal can have zero or more. The combinators that expect lenses when retrieving a value sort of accidentally try to combine multiple values together as a `Monoid` when given a Traversal. (It comes from the `Applicative` instance for `Const`, in particular.) That attempt doesn't type check in your case because no such instance exists for the target type, so you get that error message.

You probably want the `preuse` combinator instead of `use`, to account for the value potentially not being there.